# Where is the missing hard disk space?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, disk-usage, df

`df` tells me that the server uses 84% of the HDD it uses.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       30G   24G  4.6G  84% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           375M  216K  375M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

I am trying to search all the disk usage of every directory in the root but I cannot find the reported `24 GB` of data:

```
$ sudo du -hs -x /*
9.6M    /bin
20M /boot
8.0K    /data
12K /dev
5.8M    /etc
1.9G    /home
0   /initrd.img
60M /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/17167/task/17167/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/17167/task/17167/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/17167/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/17167/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
24K /root
216K    /run
9.4M    /sbin
8.0K    /srv
0   /sys
1.7M    /tmp
1.1G    /usr
5.3G    /var
0   /vmlinuz
```

By adding the number above I get somewhere between 8 and 9 GB. Where are the rest up to `24 GB`?

Comment: `ncdu` report similar numbers (i.e. still many GB missing)